# How can I select starting from where id equals some value after order by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I want to select records starting at the row where a particular id is found after the order by and I'm not sure how to do that. Mainly because our batch processing of this data stopped at a particular id and I need to resume from that id to add that data to a file (start back pulling the data where that id is located).

Here's my query:

```
Select * from TABLE_A a left join TABLE_B b
       on a.TABLE_B_ID = b.TABLE_B_ID
    WHERE b.CODE is not null and b.OTHER_FIELD is not null
    ORDER BY a.TABLE_A_ID
    //STARTING WITH a.TABLE_A_ID = 344456 <---I want to do something like this. How?
```

Comment: If your `table_id` column is symmetric and has no missing values, i.e. id 344456 is at the same (344456th) position, using `OFFSET` is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move the condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A a LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b
    ON a.TABLE_B_ID = b.TABLE_B_ID
WHERE b.CODE IS NOT NULL
AND b.OTHER_FIELD IS NOT NULL
AND a.TABLE_A_ID >= 344456
ORDER BY a.TABLE_A_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter before the `ORDER BY` using `>=`:

```sql
Select *
from   TABLE_A a
       INNER JOIN TABLE_B b
       on a.TABLE_B_ID = b.TABLE_B_ID
WHERE  b.CODE is not null
AND    b.OTHER_FIELD is not null
AND    a.TABLE_A_ID >= 344456
ORDER BY a.TABLE_A_ID
```

Note: If you require `b.other_field` or `b.code` to be non-`NULL` then you are implicitly converting the join from a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` as there will never be a case when an `OUTER JOIN` occurs and those columns are non-`NULL`.

If you do want an `OUTER JOIN` then filter in the join condition:

```sql
Select *
from   TABLE_A a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B b
       on (   a.TABLE_B_ID = b.TABLE_B_ID
          AND b.CODE is not null
          AND b.OTHER_FIELD is not null
          )
WHERE  a.TABLE_A_ID >= 344456
ORDER BY a.TABLE_A_ID
```